# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to add a submodule to a git repo like this:

```
git submodule add git://repo my/dir/here
git submodule init
```

And I get this error:
        `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core;C:\.....;c:\Program  Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\'`

The `C:\Program Files` part has a lot more paths listed, it is shortened here for brevity.

Whats going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are at the root of the repository. Git submodule commands only work from there.

Comment: I am at the root. There is a different error generated when not at the root (something about submodule commands only working from the root)

Comment: The only other time I've seen this is if there was a problem with the msysgit install. Reinstall it and make sure you do that as an admin.

Comment: k, thanks. It's actually a brand-new install. But i'll try again and let you know.